# Feeling like a hair stuck in my throat - could it be a "singing injury"?

Tags: voice

I've felt for a few days a bit like I've got a hair stuck in the back of my throat - but I figure after that length of time it can't actually be a hair.

Is this something singers would recognise as a sign of straining/damaging their vocal chords, i.e. is it a classic symptom singing teachers would be familiar with?

It doesn't hurt and it doesn't seem to affect my singing.

Comment: It's something doctors would be more familiar with, too. They'll give you a good answer, and probably a cure and preventative as well.

Comment: Well true, but checking if it's a common thing makes sense. Just like a brand-new guitarist might worry "why do my fingers hurt"!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a medical question that should be answered by a doctor.

Comment: No, it's a question to singers. If your answer is "as a singer, you should get this looked at" then that's fine, that's a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: "as a singer, you should get this looked at"

Bahaha.

I've had something similar but it could be a number of things from onset of a throat infection to somethign actually stuck in your throat. Eg I had an ear infection for ages which affected my throat and made it feel like something was stuck.

Comment: Go see your doctor. Now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recognize that specifically as a vocal injury, though it very well could be, so I'll give you the usual advice.

Give it three or four days, drink plenty of hot tea (especially with honey, ginger, and/or lemon if you can manage it), plenty of water, and try not to overuse your voice. Specifically, no yelling over loud noises, no shouting, no strenuous or aggressive singing.

Whether it's a minor injury or something unrelated to singing may not matter so much, as once you have such a condition, the care and potential risks are very similar. If you don't feel better after several days, you might give it a full week (this may be hard for some vocalists), after which you probably want to see a doctor to be safe.

Comment: Thanks - seems good advice. It feels to me since posting more like it could have been a tickle in my throat, since my throat has since got a bit sore and dry... some low-grade cold/virus probably. Luckily I am visiting my doctor on an unrelated matter next week so I have no dilemma about whether it's worth a special trip!

Comment: A "tickle" in my throat, like it's dry, no matter how much water or tea I drink, is my usual warning sign that I need to take it easy vocally (either I'm overdoing it or I'm getting a bit sick).